# What was that weird 'shock'/EMP I received?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

During Deus Ex 3, coming back to my apartment to speak to Sarif I ignored the apartment and went straight into the downstairs elevator, after passing the corner I got a weird 'shock' which acted like a small EMP.

What on earth was it? I couldn't see a mine or anything that could've done it...

Comment: Answering this question would spoil a latter part of the game (story).

Comment: Since mordi2k has already posted the answer, I won't post another one. Another thing to note is that you will stop getting these shocks if you decide to upgrade your bioshop at the LIMB clinic in Hengsha on your second trip, but there is a (huge-ish) price to pay later on in the game for this decision.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've actually gotten to the point where I've paid the price. I upgraded my chip :)

Comment: You should mark the question as answered if it has been answered to your satisfaction (click the checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 16):

It's neither a mine, or anything you did

It's actually a part of the story, and will be somewhat explained later on in the game. What you are experiencing are in fact a "malfunction" in the biochip.

Explained it a bit better with spoilers, in case you want to know:

> The "malfunction" is actually a part of the bad guys' plan—to force all augmented people get an upgraded biochip from the LIMB clinics. This upgraded biochip has a remote-controlled "kill switch" that drives augmented people mad, and turns them in to zombies who attack everyone they see.

Comment: Is it ever stated in-game how they're causing the 'malfunctions' in the first place?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Nope, that's the reason for the"somewhat explained" statement. However there are some implications in the game like: "We've spoken with Montreal. The broadcast satellites are ours when we need them, few weeks of discomfort and the public will be primed for our recall."

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I'll finish the game tonight so I'll see what's going on, it wouldve made sense if I had spoken to Sarif in the apt first :)