# Why is there electronic static at certain occasions in Deus Ex: HR?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was that weird 'shock'/EMP I received?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31076/what-was-that-weird-shock-emp-i-received)

Well, I'm just past the part where the helicopter gets ambushed. Just as I entered Lower Hengsha, the entire game froze a bit, there was some electronic static and my things were rebooting (like I was hit by an EMP). It's happened before too.

[image]

I'm assuming this is in-game and not the fault of my computer. And uh, if this is a spoiler for the end-game, spoiler tags, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed something you figure out during the course of the game (unless you are in the habit of completely ignoring computers and the e-mails they contain).

If indeed you are impatient, take a look:

> The phenomenon you are experiencing is something that Tai-Yung medical (and someone else, who
>  I shall not name to avoid an additional unnecessary spoiler) is
>  behind, in order to prompt people to replace their "faulty" neural
>  interface augmentations with a new "improved" augmentation that does
>  not suffer from this fake problem. The new augmentation chip acts as
>  sort of a kill-switch that allows shutting off people's augmentations
>  remotely (and other things, again, I'm trying to avoid unnecessary
>  spoilers). As far as I can tell, the game never explains how this fake problem is caused, but I may have simply missed the explanation during my playthrough.
>  
>  You have a chance to replace your own chip with the "improved"
>  version.  If you do so, during a later boss fight your augmentations will be disabled.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out a couple minutes after I asked this via Pritchard in-game. Thanks anyways! I know I won't be installing it.

Comment: If you install the upgrade, your augmentations will be partially disabled during a boss fight later in the game, making it slightly more difficult.